# JavaScript - I condition "if" doesn't respond properly

Tags: javascript, html

Here is the idea behind the code: The article has an avatar object in the beginning. e.g.:

```
<div class="column-right">
  <div class="inner">
    <h3>Header of article</h3>
    <div id="avatar">
      <img>
      <div>avatar title</div>
    </div>
    <p>long text</p>
  </div>
 </div>
```

When a user scrolls down, the avatar obviously disappears. So I wanted to make a clone of said avatar and put it in the left column using position `fixed`.

Here is the JavaScript code:

```
document.body.onscroll = function(e) {
    var scrolled = document.documentElement.scrollTop;
    var newAv;

    if ( (scrolled > avatarCoords.bottom) && !newAv ) { 
        //check if user scrolled below the avatar. if clone of avatar exists, do anything:

        newAv = avatar.cloneNode(true);  
        //clone actual element, whick user can't   see right now

        newAv.style.position = "fixed";
        newAv.style.left = 2 + "px";
        newAv.style.top = 10 + "px";

        document.body.appendChild(newAv);  //add clone in document
    }

    if( (scrolled < avatarCoords.bottom) && newAv ) {
        newAv.parentNode.removeChild(newAv);
    }
}

function getCoords(element) {
    var box = element.getBoundingClientRect();
    return {
        bottom: box.top + avatar.offsetHeight
    }
}
```

I don't understand why the first condition keeps responding even though the variable **newAv** is assigned. `!newAv` is supposed to be false after first cloning.

If you can answer the first question, tell me why `newAv` can't be removed as well.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You keep redefining newAV inside the onscroll function.

Make this a global variable (so this remembers the value from previous call):

```
var newAv;
document.body.onscroll = function(e) {
  var scrolled = document.documentElement.scrollTop; // etc
```

Comment: Thank u very much! It helped.)